# Como usar o async e await no NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

estou tentando aprender a usar o async await mas, estou errando em algo e preciso de ajuda. Meu método funciona como esperado com Promise vejam:

```
import express from 'express';
import conn from '../models/connection';
const c =  conn;

class ClientRoutes {
...
    getMainPage(req, res, next) {
        c.openConection().then((a) => {
            console.log(a);
            res.render('index', {title: 'Abner'})
        })           
    }
...
```

quando eu vejo através do console.log chega normalmente os dados que preciso; a classe/método que fornece é:

```
import r from 'rethinkdb';

class Db_Conection {

    openConection(req, res, next) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            r.connect({host: process.env.DB_HOST, port: process.env.DB_PORT}, (err, conn) => {
                if ( err && err.name === 'ReqlDriverError' && err.message.indexOf( 'Could not connect' ) === 0 && ++count < 3 ) {
                    console.log( err );
                    return;                
                }
                resolve(conn);            
            })
        })
    }
...
```

**Quero transformar isso usando async e await** daí **tentei mas deu errado** o seguinte:

```
...
    async openConection(req, res, next) {
        r.connect({host: process.env.DB_HOST, port: process.env.DB_PORT}, (err, conn) => {
            if ( err && err.name === 'ReqlDriverError' && err.message.indexOf( 'Could not connect' ) === 0 && ++count < 3 ) {
                console.log( err );
                return;                
            }
            return conn;            
        })
    }
...
```

Acima o retorna vira um promise, até ai ok... Mas quando vou receber só me retorna undefined.

```
...
    async getMainPage(req, res, next) {
        const b = await c.openConection();
        console.log(b);
        // res.render('index', {title: 'Abner'})
    }
...
```

Não sei onde estou errando. Ficarei grato por sua ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está que você não precisa mexer na openConnection. Para usar async/await, a função chamada deve obrigatoriamente retornar uma Promise. Veja a referência da [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas). Logo, seu código deveria ficar:

```
openConection(req, res, next) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        r.connect({host: process.env.DB_HOST, port: process.env.DB_PORT}, (err, conn) => {
            if(err)
                 return reject(err)
            resolve(conn);            
        })
    })
}
```

No open connection permanece tudo normal, e a mudança seria somente no getMainPage que se torna:

```
async getMainPage(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const b = await c.openConnection();
        console.log(b);
        res.render('index', {title: 'Abner'})
    } catch (error) {
        // Caso a promise seja rejeitada, trata o erro
        console.error(error)
        res.status(500).json({mgs: "Um erro ocorreu"})
    }
}
```

Só um adendo, tive a liberdade de usar reject na Promise, para poder deixar que se trate o erro na função que tá chamando, tornando o código mais "desacoplado".

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado.